# convert to wide format and set 0 if value does not exists

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

I have following dataset:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(
        bnames = c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T3"),
        events = c("I", "O", "I", "I", "O"),
        freq = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I want to convert this dataset to wide format, my approach (using `reshape` package):

```
dataset2 <- melt(dataset1, id.vars = c("bnames", "events"))
dataset2 <- dataset2[c("bnames", "events", "value")]
names(dataset2) <- c("bnames", "events", "freq")
```

content of `dataset2`:

```
  bnames events freq
1     T1      I    1
2     T1      O    2
3     T2      I    3
4     T3      I    4
5     T3      O    5
```

But there should always be two rows with the same name under `bnames` column. One row with `I` and another with `O` under `events` column. If the corresponding value does not exists in original dataset (`dataset1`) then the value under `freq` should always be 0. So my desired result in this case should be:

```
  bnames events freq
1     T1      I    1
2     T1      O    2
3     T2      I    3
4     T2      O    0
5     T3      I    4
6     T3      O    5
```

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: what's the difference between `dataset1` and `dataset2` ?

Comment: @mtoto `dataset1` are original data and `dataset2` are final data after wrangling.

Comment: they look like the same to me

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way in base R:

```
left_hand <- expand.grid(
        bnames = unique(dataset1$bnames), 
        events = c("I", "O"), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )

dataset2 <- merge(left_hand, dataset2, all.x = TRUE)
dataset2[is.na(dataset2)] <- 0
```

Alternatively, there is a one-liner in `tidyr` package:

```
tidyr::complete(dataset2, bnames, events, fill = list(freq = 0))
```

Comment: In the `tidyr` example, should it be `dataset1` instead of `dataset2`? (`tidyr::complete(dataset1, bnames, events, fill = list(freq = 0))`)

Comment: um, looking carefully, isn't `dataset1` identical to `dataset2`?

Comment: Yes you're right - sorry - it wasn't obvious to me on first reading of question. Nice `tidyr::complete` example BTW +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Generate all possible permutations of bnames and events, left join this set with original dataset, and return the frequency if available else set to 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset1)[CJ(bnames=bnames, events=events, unique=TRUE), 
    .(freq=ifelse(is.na(freq), 0, freq)), 
    by=.EACHI, 
    on=.(bnames, events)]

#   bnames events freq
#1:     T1      I    1
#2:     T1      O    2
#3:     T2      I    3
#4:     T2      O    0
#5:     T3      I    4
#6:     T3      O    5
```